# Is the Zalman ZM-RSSC 5.1 USB Sound Card supported in Linux?

Tags: audio

And to what extent does this card have support in Linux?

Comment: Did you try it and it did not work or are you considering buying one? A quick google search showed http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=429754 which indicates there is support in alsa but there are issues with getting 5.1 running.

Comment: Why are these questions being voted down?  They seem straight-forward enough...

Comment: I'm considering buying it, so I wanted to see some testimony from someone who has tried it out in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Just boot up your Linux installation and take a look.

1. First, find the PCI vendor and device id.

   - Look it up with the vendor if you can't find a box with the hardware connected,
   - Or (attached to Linux) use lspci -n
   - Or (attached to Windows) use regedit.exe and dig into HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI
2. Next, grep the driver name from /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.pcimap using the PCI vendor and device identifiers.

   - First column is driver name.
   - Second column is PCI vendor (when grepping, prefix with 0x0000).
   - Third column is PCI device (-||-).

When you've found out if there's a driver or not, you can use Google to find the documentation for said driver and take a look at whether it does whatever it is you want it to do.

Comment: Hard to do when you don't actually have the device yet...

Comment: @Neil: Which is why it says "look it up with the vendor", or "find a box" (read: go to a store) ;-)

Comment: A word of advice, if you can, ask in a store what is the device, not the name of that boxed incarnation. Sellers love to get chips and put different names in them (frequently seen with graphic cards bearing so many different names, when they're actually `AMD/ATi Radeon` or `nVidia GeForce`). What usually matters for support is the device itself, not whatever says in the box. In a nutshell, try to get one box open so you can look at the IC in it and read the numbers and names written over it.